# Net Core: Copy Real Database into Entity Framework InMemoryDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way to copy a Real database with a Few sample records into EntityFramework Inmemory Db. We are using Redgate Seed DataGenerator on a real physical database, to seed  data into our 1000 tables. We want to copy some of this data into our inmemory tests to validate few items. Is there anyway to conduct this? Real Database only has a few lines per table, around sample 2MB max.

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDb")
                .Options;
```

Comment: I think following actions should do the work: read required data from real db context, detatch data from contex, add it to inmemory context, call SaveChangesAsync()

Comment: hi @Artur feel to write code in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: @Artur: You wouldn't do that as part of a test. It makes your test inherently dependent on an external service, which is wrong for a number of reasons.

Comment: @AlanWalker: In general, you shouldn't do this. The in-memory database is best viewed as a mock. Add only the data that you need for the specific test. You want to run tests often (during development, automated builds, etc.). Reading from a real data source not only makes your test fragile, but also adds significant time and load to the test.

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/75678526/2736742