# Create entity framework in-memory database from an existing mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've developed an ASP.Net Core Web application connected to 2 MySQL databases and now, I'm writing unit and integration tests for my code. I chose to use Entity Framework in-Memory databases for my tests.

But the problem is that my app uses static datas stored on those MySQL databases. **Is there a way to clone those 2 databases (with datas) in-memory at my tests startup**?

PS: Data size contains about 50,000 rows.

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418988/net-core-copy-real-database-into-entity-framework-inmemorydb

Comment: my problem is still not solved on the question from the link

Comment: for unit tests, you should load just minimum data that is needed for the tests (as already commented from the shared link above). for integration tests, you should use real database. So actually there is no reason for trying to achieve what you want here (I'm afraid that your problem will never be solved here on SO). For the actual requirement, it's in fact like copying data from one database to another database which shares the same entity models (tables & schemas). You can have it done but really it does not make sense.

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/75678526/2736742